# Is it possible to expand $\sin(2x+1)\cdot\sin(2x+1)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to treat it as a binomial?

Comment: What about $\sin^2(2x+1)$?

Comment: I need to expand if it's even possible.

Comment: Would you accept $\sin^2(2x + 1) = 1 - \cos^2\left(2x + 1\right)$ ?

Comment: Yeah. I'm just trying to find the derivative of sine using limit defination. I'm also a bit curious to know where you derived cos2x=cossquared x - sinessquared x.

Comment: @KapookyHandy: It can be easily derived using $\cos(A+B) = \cos A\cos B - \sin A\sin B$. Put $\theta = A = B$ . Then use $\cos^2x = 1 - \sin^2x$. Presto, you've derived an equation for $\cos2\theta$, I've put a link to a video in my answer which will hopefully be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that [$\cos2\theta = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGk2CpbEl8I) $\implies \sin^2\theta = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos2\theta\right)$

Putting $\theta = 2x + 1$,
$$
\sin^2(2x + 1) = \frac{1}{2}\Big( 1 - \cos(4x + 2) \Big)
$$

Comment: That was awesome. Trig is by far my favorite subject in math by a long shot!